# How to customize navigation bar `y-position` in such a way that it's must be below status bar, for both iOS 6 and 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

How to customize navigation bar `y-position` in such a way that it's must be below status bar, for both iOS 6 and 7?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of proposed solutions to this problem but in my view the best is placing the below method inside the view controller

```
- (UIRectEdge) edgesForExtendedLayout {
 return UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

By using this you don't need to put a check for OS version since this is called only in ios7

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to the viewController's viewDidLoad.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    if( [self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)] ) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird. Can you post some code or screenshots ?

Comment: OK, tell me something - (1) What is the size of that image ? (should be 44 pixels.) (2) Is the status bar shown on ios6 ? (3) What is the text colour of the status bar ? (if its black on a black background, you'll only see the green battery indicator on the top left in which case you need to set the status bar style).

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
float currentVersion = 7.0;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= currentVersion) {
    // iOS 7
    self.navBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.navBar.frame.origin.x, self.navBar.frame.origin.y, self.navBar.frame.size.width, 64);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly using autolayout is the only solution that worked for me, well, aside from setting the navbar frame itself. You'll have to set a constraint for the distance of the navbar to the bottom of your view, and it's horizontal position too to silence ambiguous constraints warning . The problem with that would be the different screen heights of iphones. You can programatically add the constraint taking into account the screen's size or do it on interface builder, create an outlet to it, and set the constraint's constant with regard to the current screen size.

You'll have to understand though that in ios 7 your view is expanded to cover the whole length of the screen, that is, a part of your view that is shown under the status bar ( and I don't think you can override this using `edgesForExtendedLayout`). So it is your responsibility to show something under the status bar and yes it could wreck havoc on the layout of the elements of your view. again I find autolayout good for this.

One more thing, if this navigationbar is the navigation bar of a navigation controller, I don't think you could ever do what you want in ios 7

Answer (score 0):

```
 UINavigationController *navCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ecLoginViewCont];


    [navCont.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NAVIGATIONBAR_IMAGE] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


    self.window.rootViewController = navCont;
```